# How to determine browser forward or backward in ajax app

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have an ajax application that uses hashbanging for navigation and I keep track of the navigation stack in my application. Is there any good way of determine if the user presses the back button in the browser or just pressing a link going to the same url.

Example: Lets assume the user is at http://mysite.com/#home, and then presses a link going to http://mysite.com/#settings. This new settings page contains a link to http//mysite.com/#home. How can i determine if the user presses the link to go back to home or if the users presses the back button on the browser.

Since I internally keep track of the history stack I would like to know if I should push or pop the url of the stack.

One solution would be to poison the url with a counter or timestamp, but it would be nice to avoid.

Comment: Could you share more details on how exactly you use hashes for navigation? Normally, there's no need to track the history in code.

Comment: Actually the only reason for tracking this is to determine the direction of some transition animation. It is not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about hashbang and use html5 [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). When the page history changes, he [popState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate) event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the user pressed the link:

```
var link = document.getElementById("backLink"), pressedBackLink;
link.addEventListener("click", function() {
    pressedBackLink = true;
    // Do stuff here
}, false);

function hashChange() {
    if (pressedBackLink) {
        pressedBackLink = false;
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

Remember to use `attachEvent` for IE<9. I supposed that your link has id `"backLink"` and your listener on the `haschange` event is the function `hashChange`.

About the back browser button, there's no way to determine it. The user could have clicked forward, too, or any other link on his history without following them sequentially. Don't waste your time in that.

Comment: Thanks! Picking up the event from the link is easy, I just wanted to know if the was a good way to find out if the user is moving forward or backwards in the browser history. If not I will find other ways of handling my problems.